# PHP Intelelephense in Visual Studio Code

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code to develop in PHP.
I installed PHP Intelephense Extension for my visual studio code. But name of class do not highlight with any color. The name of class is white color:

[image: my Visual Studio code]

I want the color of `Role` class the same below image. I have searched google but I don't have any keyword for this.

[image: Expected]

Comment: Solved by a way: Select `File` > `Preferences` > `Color Theme` > `Dark +`

Comment: This is exactly how I resolved my problem as well. Setting the Color Theme back to a 'default' theme. I did a VSC restart after setting. After that, it seemed I could switch to other themes and php/html would color correctly.

Answer (score -2):

have you tried [PHP IntelliSense by Felix Becker](https://github.com/felixfbecker/vscode-php-intellisense) ? I've been using it for almost a year, and got no issues.

--EDIT--

for inteliphense, have you set **php.executablePath** in VS Code? hit CTRL+Shift+P and type in `settings`, then select `open user settings`.

in the `settings.json` file add `"php.executablePath":"[path to your php executable]"`

hope this helps

Comment: Hi Rangga!. I tried to this way but it isn't effective